# Problema módulo Arduino

Tags: arduino

estoy intentando cargar un programa en un módulo Arduino, pero cuando le doy a subir el programa me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error

```
El Sketch usa 7206 bytes (22%) del espacio de almacenamiento de programa. El 
máximo es 32256 bytes.
Las variables Globales usan 495 bytes (24%) de la memoria dinámica, dejando 
1553 bytes para las variables locales. El máximo es 2048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xb8
Problema subiendo a la placa. Visita 
http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload para sugerencias.
```

Perdón se me olvidaba poner el código:

```
#include <Wire.h> // This library allows you to communicate with I2C 
devices.
const int MPU_ADDR = 0x68; // I2C address of the MPU-6050. If AD0 pin is set 
to HIGH, the I2C address will be 0x69.
int16_t accelerometer_x, accelerometer_y, accelerometer_z; // variables for 
accelerometer raw data
int16_t gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z; // variables for gyro raw data
int16_t temperature; // variables for temperature data
char tmp_str[7]; // temporary variable used in convert function
char* convert_int16_to_str(int16_t i) { // converts int16 to string. 
Moreover, resulting strings will have the same length in the debug monitor.
sprintf(tmp_str, "%6d", i);
return tmp_str;
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR); // Begins a transmission to the I2C 
  slave (GY-521 board)
  Wire.write(0x6B); // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0); // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
}
void loop() {
   Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR);
   Wire.write(0x3B); // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) [MPU-6000 
   and MPU-6050 Register Map and Descriptions Revision 4.2, p.40]
   Wire.endTransmission(false); // the parameter indicates that the Arduino 
   will send a restart. As a result, the connection is kept active.
   Wire.requestFrom(MPU_ADDR, 7*2, true); // request a total of 7*2=14 
   registers

  // "Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();" means two registers are read and stored 
  in the same variable
  accelerometer_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3B 
  (ACCEL_XOUT_H) and 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  accelerometer_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3D 
  (ACCEL_YOUT_H) and 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  accelerometer_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3F 
  (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) and 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  temperature = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x41 
  (TEMP_OUT_H) and 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  gyro_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x43 
  (GYRO_XOUT_H) and 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  gyro_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x45 
  (GYRO_YOUT_H) and 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  gyro_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x47 
  (GYRO_ZOUT_H) and 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)

  // print out data
  Serial.print("aX = "); 
  Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_x));
  Serial.print(" | aY = "); 
  Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_y));
  Serial.print(" | aZ = "); 
  Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_z));
  // the following equation was taken from the documentation [MPU-6000/MPU-
  6050 Register Map and Description, p.30]
  Serial.print(" | tmp = "); Serial.print(temperature/340.00+36.53);
  Serial.print(" | gX = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_x));
  Serial.print(" | gY = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_y));
  Serial.print(" | gZ = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_z));
  Serial.println();

  // delay
  delay(1000);
 }
```

He revisado todas todo y no entiendo el problema ¿alguien conoce el motivo, o si puede ser, la solución?

Un saludo

Comment: Este problema puede deberse a varias causas, echa un ojo a esta web donde te dan varias opciones a ver si alguna te ayuda http://www.instructables.com/id/A-solution-to-avrdude-stk500getsync-not-in-syn/

Comment: He comprobado todas las opciones que pueden causar el fallo, pero nada, me sigue saliendo lo mismo...

Comment: Este es un problema común con Arduino. La única solución es conectar/desconectar o invocar a los espiritus.